# what is the largest gap between rank and approximate rank

Tags: communication-complexity, linear-algebra, computer-science

$\epsilon$-approximation rank of a matrix $M$ is the minimum rank of a real matrix $A$ which differs from $M$ at most $\epsilon$ in each entry. Associating any function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow${1,-1} with a $(1,-1)$ matrix $M_f$ of size $|X|\times |Y|$. We know the log of rank of $M_f$ is lower bound of deterministic communication complexity of $f$ and the log of approximation rank of $M_f$ is lower bound of randomized communication complexity. The largest gap between deterministic communication complexity and randomized communication complexity is exponential. So how about the largest gap between rank and approximation rank?

Comment: How about comparing the zero matrix with ${\epsilon}I$ ? Or am I missing something?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.14

Comment: @Gerhard No 0's. But what about $J$ vs $\epsilon I+J$ With $J$ the all $1$'s matrix of the appropriate shape and $I$ the usual identity maxtrix with possible rows or columns of all $0$ to pad it to the correct size.

Comment: @Aaron, the way I read the problem, $M$ is to have $\pm1$ entries, and the matrix $A$ differing from $M$ by at most $\epsilon$ is to have as small a rank as possible. Your example goes the other way. 

Comment: For example, suppose $M$ has rank 2.  $M$ must have a $2 \times 2$ submatrix $S$ that has rank 2.  We can assume wlog this is $\left(\matrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & -1\cr}\right)$.  It is then easy to see that any $2 \times 2$ matrix that differs by less than 1 from this in each entry has rank 2, so if $\epsilon < 1$ the $\epsilon$-approximation rank is 2. 

Comment: One could derive this bound from one on 0/1 matrices. Suppose M is a square full-rank -1/1 submatrix; suppose wlog that the first column is all ones; subtract this first column from all the other ones, and you remain with a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ 0-2 matrix. By going backward we see that an entrywise-$\leq\varepsilon$ perturbation of the initial matrix becomes a $\leq 2\varepsilon$ perturbation of the modified matrix. So, if we can bound the distance from singularity of full-rank, square 0/1 matrices then we can extend this result to -1/1 matrices.